# MIN/MAX not working on column pushed from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am querying data from the SQL Server, and my `SELECT` includes `CONVERT(date,[column])`.

The query runs just fine, and I pass it into a refreshable Excel workbook worksheet called 'Data'. Refreshing the workbook works just fine as well.

The issue is, on a separate 'Summary' worksheet within the same workbook, I want to run `=MIN(Data!A:A)` (let's just say the date column is in A:A). Thus, my goal is to retrieve the minimum/earliest date in that column. The result is always 0. I have tried formatting the Data column A:A as Date as well as the cell holding the `MIN` function. No matter what I do, the result seems to always be 0.

Could it be an issue with my query passing the column into Excel in an incompatible way?

Comment: When I click on the filter dropdown on the date column in Excel (Data!A:A), the individual record filters aren't organized by year, then month, then date. So it looks like Excel is not reading this column as a date? I've tried formatting it as Date as well, but it still doesn't seem to be picking it up.

Comment: @pnuts - I see, for example: 2015-10-19

Comment: Are the dates left-aligned in the cells? True dates are numerical and numbers/dates are right-aligned in a cell by default. You may have text-that-looks-like-a-date. Run a quick Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Next, Next, Date: YMD, Finish on the column to convert the text to real dates. If this works, some code could be written to automate it.

Comment: pnuts & @Jeeped - I tried Jeeped's suggestion and it definitely worked, and I'm sure yours does as well pnuts, but how should I query the data so that it comes into Excel formatted properly for a date? I've tried CONVERT(date,column) and CONVERT(varchar(10),column,101) --- (101 is for MM/DD/YYYY). Neither of them are working for my MIN purposes

Comment: Sometimes you just need some post-processing to clean things out.

Comment: @pnuts the question is open to Excel or SQL solutions. I am not sure which is most efficient, as I do not know the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast(convert(char(11), YourDateFieldHere, 113) as datetime) will do the job. You will want to create a new connection in a new tab to see your results.